# How can i make ul width same as his parent width with CSS?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a list that is displayed every time you type in a search, the problem is when I test it on small devices the width of the list was bigger than the search input or his parent and that shouldn't be happen

In small devices should always look like this:https://www.screencast.com/t/cQj9PNG9

But instead of that, it's looking like this:https://www.screencast.com/t/9LSDht6r

How can I solve it?

I already tried using this, but this overwrites the behaviour of the `col` element

```css
 .parent{
    display: contents; 
 }
```

```css
#search-box{
    border-style:none;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px ; 
    height: 3rem;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
    position:relative;
}

.divider-border{
    border-right: 2px solid #DFD6D6;
    height: auto;
}

.btn-default{
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
    outline:none !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    background: white !important;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

input:focus ~ .btn-default {
    background: white ;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn-default:focus,.btn-default:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: white;
 }

 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background : url("images/baseline_clear_black_18dp.png") ;
 }
  
  #myUL {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: fit-content;
    max-height: 13rem;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /*margin-top: -0.5px; /*This hide the line between the input and the search list*/
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;
    transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important;
    position:absolute;
    top: 47px !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #myUL li a {
    margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Grey background color */
    padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
    color: black; /* Add a black text color */
    display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
  }
  
  #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #737272; 
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    background: white;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Emails View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Searchbar -->
                    <div class="col-4 parent">
                        <div class="input-group mt-4 ml-2">
                            <input type="search" class="form-control search-radius" onkeyup="searchFilter()" name="search-template" placeholder="Search or select template " id="search-box">
                            <span class="divider-border"></span>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="search-box-btn" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul id="myUL" class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">George</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sam</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Alis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Alberto</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Searchbar -->
                
                  </div>
               


    
    </div>


<!-- Bootstrap and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function searchFilter() {
      // Declare variables
      let input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById('search-box');
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<script>
    $('#search-box').on('input', function() {
        $('#myUL').css('display', $(this).val()  !== '' ? 'block' : 'none')
    });
</script>

<script>
    let myUL = document.getElementById("myUL");
    let search = document.getElementById('search-box');
    $('#search-box-btn').click(function () { // on a click on botton
        //$('#myUL').show(); // show the div with the search results
        $('#myUL').css({
            //'margin-left' : -$('#search-box').outerWidth( true )
        }).toggle();
    })

    $("li").on("click", function(){
        $("#search-box").val($(this).text());
        $('#myUL').hide();
        // myFunction(); You can put this here if you want to search right after a user clicked
    });
</script>
    
<script>
  
    var contentBg = document.getElementById('content');
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var square1 = document.getElementById('square1');
    var square2 = document.getElementById('square2');
    var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    document.onclick = function(e){
        if(e.target.id == 'content'){
            table.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            square1.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            square2.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            ul.style.display = 'none';
        }
        
    }
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the "col-4" class in the outer container for "col-sm-4", so it occupies the 100% of width for smaller devices:

```css
#search-box{
    border-style:none;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px ; 
    height: 3rem;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
    position:relative;
}

.divider-border{
    border-right: 2px solid #DFD6D6;
    height: auto;
}

.btn-default{
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;
    background: #EEEEEE ;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
    outline:none !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    background: white !important;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

input:focus ~ .btn-default {
    background: white ;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn-default:focus,.btn-default:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: white;
 }

 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background : url("images/baseline_clear_black_18dp.png") ;
 }
  
  #myUL {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: fit-content;
    max-height: 13rem;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /*margin-top: -0.5px; /*This hide the line between the input and the search list*/
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px !important;
    transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important;
    position:absolute;
    top: 47px !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #myUL li a {
    margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Grey background color */
    padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
    color: black; /* Add a black text color */
    display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
  }
  
  #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #737272; 
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    background: white;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Emails View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Searchbar -->
                    <div class="col-sm-4 parent">
                        <div class="input-group mt-4 ml-2">
                            <input type="search" class="form-control search-radius" onkeyup="searchFilter()" name="search-template" placeholder="Search or select template " id="search-box">
                            <span class="divider-border"></span>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="search-box-btn" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul id="myUL" class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">George</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sam</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Alis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Alberto</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Searchbar -->
                
                  </div>
               


    
    </div>


<!-- Bootstrap and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function searchFilter() {
      // Declare variables
      let input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById('search-box');
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<script>
    $('#search-box').on('input', function() {
        $('#myUL').css('display', $(this).val()  !== '' ? 'block' : 'none')
    });
</script>

<script>
    let myUL = document.getElementById("myUL");
    let search = document.getElementById('search-box');
    $('#search-box-btn').click(function () { // on a click on botton
        //$('#myUL').show(); // show the div with the search results
        $('#myUL').css({
            //'margin-left' : -$('#search-box').outerWidth( true )
        }).toggle();
    })

    $("li").on("click", function(){
        $("#search-box").val($(this).text());
        $('#myUL').hide();
        // myFunction(); You can put this here if you want to search right after a user clicked
    });
</script>
    
<script>
  
    var contentBg = document.getElementById('content');
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var square1 = document.getElementById('square1');
    var square2 = document.getElementById('square2');
    var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    document.onclick = function(e){
        if(e.target.id == 'content'){
            table.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            square1.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            square2.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 0px)';
            ul.style.display = 'none';
        }
        
    }
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did it but in some points, it's still not looking good, as you can see right here: https://www.screencast.com/t/nalvysTxjZcD

Comment: I see, the thing is I tested the code I posted in chrome and firefox and they don't reproduce the issue from this last pic you added

Comment: Try testing with the responsive on mobile devices either rotate